# transferring clips skills and knowledge to drools

Tags: artificial-intelligence, drools, clips

I'm looking to get a deeper knowledge of drools, and I was wondering if CLIPS skills and knowledge would be transferable to drools?

In particular, I'm wondering if the following book would help on the quest of getting a deeper knowledge of some of the principles behind drools?

[Intelligent Systems: Principles, Paradigms and Pragmatics: Principles](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=80FXUtF5kRoC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false)?

Note: this question is answered by the comments in the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several DROOLS books available on Amazon including two published this year (2013).

Comment: The problem I have found with the Drools books is that they don't go into very much detail on the theory.  CLIPS books however tend to go into much more detail, which is why I was wondering if the knowledge contained in the CLIPS books would be transferable to Drools.

Comment: A lot of the knowledge is transferable, particularly the general knowledge of programming with rules. When using JRules I was able to start coding immediately because of my experience using CLIPS--I just had to learn the new syntax to get started. A lot of the language specific features you can pick up along the way. CLIPS, for example, uses modules to control execution where JRules uses rule flows. They're different approaches to solve the same problem, but once you understand the rationale for the feature in one language it's easier to understand a different approach in another language.